# User session management with AQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I need some help with my implementation. I may be misunderstanding the concepts here.
I have two models, user and session:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True,
                index=True, default=uuid4)
    username = Column(String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    email = Column(String(128), unique=True, index=True)
    created_time = Column(DateTime(), nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    updated_time = Column(DateTime(), nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    hashed_password = Column(String(128))

    sessions = relationship("Session",
                            back_populates="user",
                            order_by="desc(Session.created_time)",
                            lazy="dynamic")

@event.listens_for(User, 'before_update')
def update_password(_mapper, connection, target):
    sessions = target.sessions.filter(Session.active == True)
    for session in sessions:
        session.deactivate()

class Session(Base):
    __tablename__ = "sessions"
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True),
                primary_key=True,
                index=True,
                default=uuid4)
    created_time = Column(DateTime(), nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    expiration_time = Column(
        DateTime(), nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("users.id"))
    active = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)

    user = relationship("User", back_populates="sessions")

    def deactivate(self):
        self.active = False
```

The idea here is when I update a user's instance, it will automatically update its related sessions. But I am getting the following warning and no session is updated:
`SAWarning: Attribute history events accumulated on 1 previously clean instances within inner-flush event handlers have been reset, and will not result in database updates. Consider using set_committed_value() within inner-flush event handlers to avoid this warning.`

I understand why it is happening, the moment when user's deactivate is being called, the session is already flushing, so I tried using a nested session, but it gives the same result.
I already tried using set_committed_value() in user's deactivate method, but the problem persists.